# Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c#, recursion, segmentation-fault

I'm completing a pretty easy [programming excersize](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/FCTRL/) with the following code:

```
    using System;

    namespace Factorial

{
    class MainClass
    {

        static int fives(int x) {

            int r = 0;
            while(x % 5 == 0) {
                r++;
                x /= 5;
            }
            return r;

        }

        static int z(int x) {

            if (x == 1)
                return 0;
            else
                return z (x-1) + fives (x);

        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int testCases = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
            int[] xs = new int[testCases];
            for (int i=0; i<testCases; i++)
                xs [i] = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
            foreach (int x in xs)
                Console.WriteLine (z (x));
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work OK with small numbers, but with 8735373 from the example it prints "Segmentation fault: 11". Does it mean that I run out of memory because of recursion going in too deep? What causes it?

(I run C# in Mono 2.10.8 on a Mac.)

P.S.: If anyone's interested in the excersize itself, [here's my final solution](http://pastebin.com/7NHQijqx) (much more optimized).

Comment: C#? Segmentation fault? Pick one.

Comment: Have you tried to run it from debugger? Any exception details?

Comment: Oh, then maybe, although that would be weird, you'd probably get a `StackOverflowException`. Can you post more detail?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Sounds like stack-overflow to me. The `namespace Factorial` is just there to trick us, right?

Comment: I don't see any exception details even in debug mode; it looks like a regular console output rather than exception.

Comment: Tried it in LINQPad, indeed it crashes with a StackOverflowException, caused by the `return z (x-1)` if `xs[i]` is huge.

Comment: On the spoj.pl it shows "runtime error (SIGABRT)" as a status.

Comment: Michael, thanks for this detail! Now I'll have at least something to try.

Comment: I would think that int is too small for the datatype for the z function and that's blowing up with large numbers.  Try int64 or longint

Comment: @MikeTWebb C# is `unchecked` by default - a valid concern, but if you run it in the debugger: not the actual error

Comment: Still think that could be the issue and just not bubbling up correctly....do you know the lowest number where it crashes...i.e, 100,000 or 64,000? Try 32768....that's the first number larger than a small int

Comment: @MikeTWebb nah, really - it's a stack-overflow; run it in a debugger... (feel free to add some `checked` blocks to ensure it isn't silent arithmetic overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue was caused by the large amount of recursion, the error would probably be a StackOverflowException. As golergka, previously stated, I'm pretty sure it's a Mono fault. A segmentation fault occurs arises when memory is being mismanaged by trying to reach memory addresses that should not be reached. This type of error is a system error... not a C# exception. I'm almost sure that Mono isn't managing memory very well with large numbers. I hope that helps you in your research.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like an unhandled `StackOverflowException` - common when overusing recursion. So... *don't overuse recursion*. It might be fine for maths and some very specific languages (F# would probably cope), but C#... not so much.

That looks like (not verified):

```
    static int z(int x)
    {
        int accumulator = 0;
        while(x!=1)
        {
            accumulator += fives(x);
            x--;
        }
        return accumulator;
    }
```

which doesn't error - it doesn't recurse (although it does call `fives` per iteration). Even better: do the algebra to find the direct formula.

Comment: @Cicada meh... `StackOverflowException` is in that special category of crazy (along with `OutOfMemoryException`) where "random" is pretty much guaranteed.

Comment: That's exactly what I done, just a moment ago — even added my own answer before I saw yours ;)

Comment: F# tail-recursion optimization FTW!

Answer (score 2):

When you use the larger number your recursion steps is causing StackOverflowException and if you look into the debugger you will see after how many recursive steps the exception occurred.

I think Mono code somehow consider stackoverflow exception to Segmentaiton fault which could be how it is handled.

[image]

You could debug it if you wish:  [How do I debug a segmentation fault in Mono on Ubuntu without any debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320450/how-do-i-debug-a-segmentation-fault-in-mono-on-ubuntu-without-any-debugger)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that simple conversion from recursion to loop solved the problem:

```
    static int z (int x)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i=1; i<=x; i++) {
            result += fives (i);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: sure you don't want to start with `i=2` ?

Comment: I'm mainly worried about the special case of `1` when translating `z`. If your `i=5` relates to further analysis of `fives(...)`, then that is separate: the first job is to translate `z` correctly, and *you haven't done that*. It is executing `fives(1)`, which the old version ***did not***.