# C# SIGSEGV when implementing get-set-property

Tags: c#, mono, segmentation-fault

When I try to implement a get-set-property with a body and use that set, it always exits with a SIGSEGV -- a segmentation fault. I'm running Mono 2.10.9 + MonoDevelop 3.0.3.5 all under Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8). Here's the minimum amount of code I can get it to do this with:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static int Main(string[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.Bar = 42;        // Never makes it past this line
        return 0;
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public int Bar {
        get { return Bar; }
        set { Bar = value; }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a Mono bug?

Comment: I know I throw a SIGSEGV every time I see someone use `42` in an example.  Its not funny anymore, folks.  Go back to using `69`, it needs to get the dust knocked off it.

Comment: It should rather give some kind of stack overflow since you're calling the property recursively until the stack explodes... And what?? Mono bombs you with SIGSEGV errors instead of runtime exceptions?

Comment: It's probably for a similar reason as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807059/segmentation-fault-11) poster's question... Both mine and his should be stack overflow exceptions, but both are some kind of segfaults. Strange, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
public class Foo {
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

OR this:

```
public class Foo {
    private int _bar;
    public int Bar {
       get { return _bar; }
       set { _bar = value; }
    }
}
```

You don't have a backing store. You either need to add one, or use an auto property. The way your code is written you are recursively calling get/set when you are accessing those properties.

Comment: Ohhhh, I understand now. Thanks! I feel so careless. :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use auto-implemented properties:

```
public int Bar { get; set; }
```

or you can work with field:

```
private int _bar;
public int Bar 
{ 
    get { return value; } 
    set { _bar = value; } 
}
```